# How to render a component B only after selecting a radio button in component A in react js?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, rendering

I am new to React. I have three components A,B and C .I need to render C only after selecting a radio button which is listed in A. I am not finding a way to do it.Could some one suggest best approach to do this?

Comment: Can you show us an attempt at solving this issue yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is basically that something "higher up" both A and C should store a variable to tell if C is visible, and then pass it down to C. That something higher up could be their parent's state, or a mobx store, or a variable set on a hook... anything both A and C can access and that would trigger a rerender in C when its value changed.

In the olden days, we'd do something like:

```
class ParentComponent extends React {
    state = { showC: false }
    toggleShowC = () => this.setState({ showC: !this.state.showC })
    render () {
        <>
            <A toggleShowC={this.toggleShowC} />
            <B />
            <C showC={this.state.showC} />
        </>
    }
}

const C = props => (
    props.showC
        ? <The goodies go here />
        : null
)
```

This is not a very sophisticated example. I encourage you to try and recreate something like this using [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).